# pytorch inference lead to memory leak in cpu

Tags: pytorch

I inference using pytorch model, I got memory leak problem, my code as follow:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from memory_profiler import profile


@profile(func=None, stream=open('./mem.log', 'w'))
def run(net, x):
    with x:
        net(x)


class ConvVerify(nn.Module):

    def init(self):
        for name, m in self.named_modules():
            # print(name, m)
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight, mode='fan_out')
                if m.bias is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
            elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
                nn.init.constant_(m.running_mean, 0)
                nn.init.constant_(m.running_var, 1)
                if m.weight is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.weight, 1)
                if m.bias is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)

    def __init__(self):
        super(ConvVerify, self).__init__()

        stride = 1
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(288, 64, (2, 2), stride),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )
        self.init()

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)


def begin():
    conv_verify_inst = ConvVerify()
    x = torch.autograd.Variable(torch.rand(1, 288, 7, 7))
    for i in range(3000):
        run(conv_verify_inst, x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    begin()
```

When run some iterator, the memory will increate 0.1M or 0.2M. For exmple, base memory is 71.8 MiB, finally, the memory increated to 72 MiB

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be a bug report on pytorch's github

Comment: the code as provided produce errors when executed; can you check to see if you haven't miss something.? the line `with x` in the `run` function seems to cause error

Comment: I will also report this problem on pytorch github. @Shai

Comment: @Alka, you are right, the code has error. should dropout ```with x: net(x)``` instead of "net(x)"